# What is wrong with "keccak256(abi.encode(_a ^ _b))" considering merkle tree security?

Tags: security, cryptography, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

In this article [MERKLE PROOFS FOR OFFLINE DATA INTEGRITY](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/merkle-proofs-for-offline-data-integrity/) there is a paragraph:

> Warning: Cryptography is harder than it looks. The initial version of
> this article had the hash function hash(a^b). That was a bad idea
> because it meant that if you knew the legitimate values of a and b you
> could use b' = a^b^a' to prove any desired a' value. With this
> function you'd have to calculate b' such that hash(a') ^ hash(b') is
> equal to a known value (the next branch on the way to root), which is
> a lot harder.

I can see that this [code](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org-website/pull/6466/commits/e49d4c507d07648307b89d8e28d3726cc0cf28d3#diff-93dd22cc44e29d95bdefb71a8fdc60a5c74776c8c63ed21d024805e98a5aec2fL206) seems to be insecure:

```
function pairHash(uint _a, uint _b) internal pure returns(uint) {
  return uint(keccak256(abi.encode(_a ^ _b)));
}
```

Could somebody explain why and provide an example(real code appreciated)? Or maybe just a URL to corresponding article (the closest one I've found is this [one](https://github.com/code-423n4/2022-05-factorydao-findings/issues/58))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have two values `a` and `b` and we create the pair as `hash(a^b)`. The issue is that we can create the same pair by passing two different values `a'` and `b'` such that `b' = a^b^a'` for every `a'`.

The proof is easily done knowing that the xor operation is commutative and `x^x = 0`:

```
hash(a'^b') = hash(a'^(a^b^a')) = hash(a'^a'^a^b) = hash(a^b)
```

The most basic example is a tree with `a` and `b` as only leaves, so with root equal `hash(a^b)`. Let's say the leaves are tokens amounts for an airdrop. We are supposed to claim the tokens by passing `a` as value and `[b]` as merkle proof for example. However someone can pass any value `a'` with proof `[a^b^a']`, as this still verifies the merkle root.

(PS: the issue from the codearena audit is a different one)